# Is there a way to track what a user types in Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I'm wondering if there is a way to track what a user has typed in swift playgrounds and display it in a live playground? I can't seem to find any information regarding this online. Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

To handle pressed keys you should override `keyDown` or `keyUp` methods of your `SKScene` for instance:

```swift
class MyScene: SKScene {
    
    public override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.keyDown(with: event)
        handleKeyEvent(event: event, down: true)
    }
        
    public override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.keyUp(with: event)
        handleKeyEvent(event: event, down: false)
    }
    
    func handleKeyEvent(event: NSEvent, down: Bool) {
        if let key = event.characters?.first {
            print("Key: '\(key)' - \(down ? "Down" : "Up")")
        }
    }
}

let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1024, height: 768))
let scene = MyScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
view.presentScene(scene)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```